# Как сделать кроссплатформенное приложение на HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, мобильные-приложения, кроссплатформенность

Я написал html-станицу (css, js). Работает автономно, интернет не нужен.

Как из этой страницы сделать кроссплатформенное приложение? 
подразумевается мобильная разработка

Comment: А вы можете уточнить что значит приложение? Что вы именно хотите?

Comment: У меня есть html-страница. Хочу сделать из неё приложение. Слышал, что из html ля-ля-ля можно сделать кроссплатформенное приложение пусть и в браузере

Comment: @Виктор, если ваша страница уже выполняет те функции, которые вы от неё хотите - то это уже и есть кросплатформенное приложение в браузере. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @Виктор отредактируйте ваш вопрос, добавьте это в ответ, что хотите кроссплатформенное приложение на HTML.

Comment: "В чём проблема-то?" Как я её продавать буду?

Comment: @Виктор Вам дали ответы, где перечислены возможные технологии. Но писать за вас это приложение здесь никто не будет.

Comment: @Виктор А под кроссплатформенностью вы имеете ввиду только мобильные платформы или по возможности все?

Comment: @Виктор, думаете заработать продажами приложений? Ну-ну, удачи.

Comment: Под мобильники.

Comment: @avp А что плохого в самой цели зарабатывать на продаже приложений? Пусть человек хотя бы попробует. Плюс он нигде не сказал, что будет это делать уже завтра.

Comment: Виктор, раз под мобильные платформы, вам тогда прекрасно подходит ответ @redroid.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ничего плохого. Только малореалистично. Потому что, тут с одной стороны, огромное количество бесплатного софта (включая ОС), распространяемого сторонниками идеи *информация должна быть свободной*, а с другой, армия таких же, как ТС, неотличимых друг от друга ремесленников.

Comment: Можно использовать PhoneGap, его бесплатную производную Cordova,или надстройку над Cordova в виде ionic, PhoneGap удобен тем что есть удобное ПО для разработки, то бишь ставишь на телефон  и компьютер PhoneGap и можно видеть приложение на телефоне не ставя его и отлаживать практически в режиме реального времени.

Answer (score 4):

Данный вопрос нельзя ответить объективно, так как существует несколько технологий, позволяющих это сделать. Как минимум (основанные на Chromium):

- [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)
- [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework)
- [AppJS](http://appjs.com/)

Comment: Из популярных решений для десктопа можно также отметить [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/).

Answer (score 4):

Солидарен с Vadim Ovchinnikov ,и дополню список популярных Mobile App UI Frameworks:

http://ionicframework.com/

https://cordova.apache.org/

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html

[10 Best Hybrid Mobile App UI Frameworks](http://noeticforce.com/best-hybrid-mobile-app-ui-frameworks-html5-js-css)

Из всего перечисленного я юзал `ionic` , очень классная штука, меня в свое время она сильно удивила.

Comment: Я бы уточнил в ответе, что речь у вас идёт именно про мобильную разработку.

Comment: резонно, дополнил.